# Convert String Date to DateTime in email

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I showing date in email that is in string. I want to convert that into DateTime like(dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm am/pm). I am trying like DateTime.parse() but it won't work. It's failed and shows the message

> "First error: Invalid date/time: 2015-11-05"

My code line is:

```
string  nextDate = (string.valueof(cf.Last_Reviewed_date__c+
              integer.valueof(cf.CF_Section__r.CF_Review_Period__c)).substringbefore(' '));
```

need convert 'nextdate' date to datetime format and show like 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm am/pm' format. nextdate contains "2015-11-05".

Comment: are yo using visualforce email template or you are sending through apex ?

Comment: @Himanshu, sending through apex.

Comment: understood. what is this returning integer.valueof(cf.CF_Section__r.CF_Review_Period__c)).substringbefore(' ') ?

Comment: @Himanshu, Date like "2015-11-05".

Comment: I am getting confused. you already have a date cf.Last_Reviewed_date__c and you are concatenating integer.valueOf(cf.CF_Section__r.CF_Review_Period__c) which will return an integer? in that way it is not going to be added because you are using String.valueOf method.

so let me know one thing. what is the data type of cf.CF_Section__r.CF_Review_Period__c and one sample value of that. Update your question with these values.

Comment: Leave that, I added string  nextDate = (string.valueof(cf.Last_Reviewed_date__c+integer.valueof(cf.CF_Section__r.CF_Review_Period__c)).substringbefore(' '));
nextDate +=' 00:00:00';
Datetime myDate = datetime.valueOf(nextDate);
String sdate=myDate.format('dd-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a');
myDate showing time as '2013-10-04 18:30:00' and sdate showing time'05-Oct-2013 12:00 AM' why it's showing 12:00 AM.  how can we make this to show correct format like '05-Oct-2013 6:30 PM'

Comment: @VijayKumar Your String doesn't have a time in it. Why are you expecting a time of "6:30pm" when you're only putting in "2015-11-05"? Where are you getting the time from?